# javafx listener on BooleanBinding

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

Is it possible to add listeners to BooleanBindings?

I have

```
        schedule.disableProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                System.out.println("schedule.disableProperty(). " + schedule.disableProperty().get());
            }
        });
        BooleanBinding scheduleEnabled = schedule.disableProperty().not();
        scheduleEnabled.addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                System.out.println("scheduleEnabled " + scheduleEnabled.get());
            }
        });
```

Only the 1st listener shows on System.out but not the second.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as if `scheduleEnabled` is just garbage collected because there is no more reference to it.